# How do terminals programmatically block the backspace at a shell prompt so you can't backspace over it, e.g. $ for bash or C:\blah\>

Tags: c++, c, windows, bash

Do they insert any special, hidden characters into the text stream or do they just hard code it some other way and then update the position when the buffer is scrolled? Bash looks like it might because there's typically a blank space after the prompt. If it's a special character, what character is it?

Comment: The input buffer and the terminal output are two separate things. The input you type isn't *stored* in the terminal screen.

Comment: They operate in raw no-echo terminal mode. This roughly means intercepting everything you type, doing something intelligent with it, then showing you the result. Have you ever used a full-screen terminal editor such as vim? Bash is doing the same thing, only with one line.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal has distinct input and output streams.

The fact that you see what you type is because the terminal is echoing some of your input back to you.

The prompt is not *your* input, so your backspaces would not normally go past it and distort the prompt.

```
              me@host> ls -l
terminal's -> ^^^^^^^^^~~~~~ <- yours
```

Comment: So you have a terminal input buffer of X size and echo just copies the contents of that buffer one character at a time back into the screen as you're typing? Well thanks, that makes perfect sense.